# Thingsboard Widget REST API Call

Tags: rest, widget, thingsboard

Trying to make a thingsboard widget that will use current value data and allow the user to send an RPC request based on this latest value data.  This doesn't seem work in a Control widget because I can't get latest value data and doesn't seem to work in a latest value widget because I can't send an RPC.  I was thinking I can short cut this and just use the REST API to send the RPC.  However, I can't seem to do this as I would need access to the token to to make the REST call?  Is the currently logged in users token available for a rest calls within a widget somehow?  Any other ideas how to achieve my goal of having latest values and sending an RPC in the same widget?

Answer (score 0):

you can make latest value custom widget

then RPC request using latest value in action

use service to call make RPC request no need of JWT token